# Python Using PyAudio how to write microphone output to text file and read at receiver side to create wave file

Tags: python, stream, eval, wave, repr

i have code written as given below . It works perfectly . Now i want to save the output of microphone in text file .

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=18,
            rate=44100,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=1024,
            output_device_index=1)

for i in range(0, 1000):
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
frames.append(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

target = open('target.txt', 'w')
target.write(repr(frames))
target.close()
```

It saves output in text file as given  below . (list having str elements sepereted by comma .

```
  Ex - ['' , '' , ''].


['\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc9\x00\xb2\xfe\x82\x02\xf7\ts\xfen\x00i\xff\xeb\xff\xa9\xff\xed\xff\xc5\xff\xd1\xff\xcd\xff\xaf\xff\xde\xff\xb8\xff\xc9\xff\xb0\xff\xca\xff\xd1\xff\xc9\xff\xcb\xff\xdf\xff\xdb\xff\xe2\xff\xe6\xff\xd9\xff\xf8\xff\xe1\xff\xf6\xff\xf1\xff\xd8\xff\xe1\xff\xe4\xff\xd4\xff\xdd\xff\xef\xff\xef\xff\xdc\xff\xd2\xff\xd6\xf  ....]
```

On receiver side i transfer this file .

Receiver open the text file . Convert the content using eval () function.

```
            with open("targetRec.txt",'r') as inf:      
                Rnewdiffdict  = eval(inf.read())
```

The inf.Read() returns  string object . Eval return list object .
Following code write the list to wave file .

```
            wf = wave.open("recaudio.wav", 'wb')
            wf.setnchannels(int(recmetadata[0]))
            wf.setsampwidth(int(recmetadata[2]))
            wf.setframerate(int(recmetadata[3]))
            wf.writeframes(b''.join(Rnewdiffdict))       
            #  Write frames in wave file . 
            wf.close()    #  Close wave file.
```

Now , at sender side , i want to replace \x by ' ' while sending  . It can reduce text file size .

```
          target.write(repr(frames).replace('\\x',' '))
```

At receiver side , i want to replace ' '   by \x  to recreate file as it was  before the replace operation at sender side  .

```
           Rnewdiffdict  = eval(inf.read().replace(' ','\\x'))
```

It gives me error and then program hang  .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\read wave.py", line 239, in <module>
ReceiveAudio()
  File "I:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\read wave.py", line 101, in ReceiveAudio
    Rnewdiffdict  = eval(inf.read().replace(' ','\\x'))
  File "<string>", line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced code at sender side as given below.

```
target = open('target.txt', 'w')    
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(repr(frames))   ## Encode using base64
target.write(encoded_string)
```

On receiver side code is written as below -

```
with open("targetRec.txt",'r') as inf:
      x = inf.read() 
      y = x.decode('base64')               ## Decode using base64
      z = eval(y)
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to this .